# How to apply the same Distort effect to a batch of Adobe Illustrator files?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, batch-processing, actions, distort

I'm trying to batch apply one specific Distort Effect to several different AI files at the same time. These are the settings for the Distort Effect I'm trying to apply:

Distort / Tweak with the following settings:

```
Horizontal = 5% 
Vertical = 4%

Relative (checked)

Modify:
Anchor Points (checked)
‘In’ Control Points (checked)
‘Out’ Control Points (checked)
```

I can do this myself to each AI file by hand, but if I want to apply this same effect to 100 different files, that would take a long time.

I tried recording an action, but for some reason the action didn’t record the Distort.

I’m using Illustrator CC 2014.

**Is there any way to batch apply a Distort Effect to multiple AI files? Maybe using a script?**

Answer (score 1):

to be able to record the Distort Effect, you must use the "Insert Menu Item..." option located in the Action's Panel flyout menu. However, this action will bring up the Effect dialog and you'll have to click the Ok button to dismiss it, every time you run it.

another option would be to apply the Effect manually, then create a Graphic Style out of the object with effect applied. Then you can record an Action to apply such Graphic Style to new objects. This method applies the Effect without bringing up the dialog box.